# How to set NotificationManager title?

Tags: android, notifications

I want to set a custom title for a notification, but it always sets the project name in the title. Below is my code. What is wrong in this code?

```
NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle("My Notification")
            .setContentText(messageBody)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setSound(defaultSoundUri)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    NotificationManager notificationManager =
            (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0 /* ID of notification */, notificationBuilder.build());
```

Comment: when you want to change the notification title?

Comment: I want to see "My Notification" as tittle, but it shows me my application name in tittle. @SohailZahid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using hard value at here `.setContentTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))` thats why you are seening same title always.

```
  <string name="app_name">Your App Name</string>
```

you can use dynamic value from some variable to change it.

Comment: I want to see "My Notification" in tittle, but it shows my project name..

Comment: Thank you.  @SohailZahid

Answer (score 0):

You're setting notif title as `"My Notification"`. Change it to your app name.

Comment: I want to see "My Notification" in tittle, but it shows my project name.. @UgurcanYildirim

Comment: It shouldn't be if you're not changing it anywhere else.

Comment: Now it's working. I just restart my project. Sorry it was my mistake.